# Minimum cut for a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm studying for finals and can't figure out the minimum cut for this graph:

[graph http://i58.photobucket.com/albums/g271/billmoney3/ScreenShot2013-11-04at123853PM_zpscd85ed6c.png](http://i58.photobucket.com/albums/g271/billmoney3/ScreenShot2013-11-04at123853PM_zpscd85ed6c.png)

I came up with the augmenting paths:

```
s - v1 - v4 - t
s - v3 - v6 - t
s - v2 - v5 - v6 - t
s - v2 - v3- v6 - t
```

so that it eventually looks like this, capacity is on the right:

[graph2 http://i58.photobucket.com/albums/g271/billmoney3/ScreenShot2013-11-04at123853PMggggg_zps217e4ad5.png](http://i58.photobucket.com/albums/g271/billmoney3/ScreenShot2013-11-04at123853PMggggg_zps217e4ad5.png)

I'm not sure how to come up with the minimum cut for this graph. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try to compute the maximum flow.

Certainly the arc $(v4,t)$ can only have the flow value of $3$ (why?). And the bottom one can be saturated. Thus you get the value $8$.

A corresponding cut would be $\delta(X)$ for $X=\{s,v_2,v_5,v_3,v_6\}$.

You can always find  $X$ by looking at the vertices reachable from $s$ with paths that have no edge at its maximum capacity.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that max flow = 8. I don't understand the significance of the vertexes you listed in X. Are those the ones you exclude? What edges would you draw a line through? thanks for the help!

Comment: also uploaded a new picture

Comment: @Tim The minimum cut is given by the edges leaving $X$.

Comment: ok. so the edges you would cut would be: s -> v1 and v6 -> t? I thought you had to make a nice circle around them? I can't draw a circle with those two without including the edges v1 - > v2 or v1 ->v5 or v4 -> v5. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: In a minimum cut you only count the edges that leave $X$. The edges v1->v5 and v4->v5 are directed towards $X$.

Comment: oooo ok! thanks man I really understand min cut now!